# why assignable between "void" and "unknown" in function's return type?

Tags: typescript, function, types, covariance, void

i think i had meet a paradox in typescript:
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAggjGLGATApgYwDYEMBOSxqQC5gYBcYAbgPYCWCA3AFCiQBMs8y62u+RARmQCuAOwDWwygHdhjZhADM7YmAC8YPnTDB4SLFkpYwBABb7pYY7qRNwEACxK+q4pu1gJYXfqwMbYADIwcHiEYABmMGoAFACUZFS0qgB8YADeYDgEglgyYAC+fv5swbzhbNFxYCLiUsLJaRmE2bkFzP6KwRHOYSyu8B5eBoUOneXhUH3ulJ56Q0A)

```
/* A1 */ declare let a: void;
/* A2 */ declare let b: unknown;
/* A3 */ a = b; // error thrown here
/* A4 */ b = a; // no error

/* L1 */ let f1 = (): void => { return; }
/* L2 */ let f2 = (): unknown => { return; }
/* L3 */ f1 = f2; // no error
/* L4 */ f2 = f1; // no error
```

actually the range of void is actually more narrowly than unknown, A3 will throw an error.

then, with type theory of Covariance & Contravariance, we can preduce that one of L3/L4 should also throw an error, but it doesn't.

why ?

Comment: You can open an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript)

Comment: I wouldn't open an issue.  There's already https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8581.  See the answer to the linked question for more information.